# Autocompleting MVC View Variables in Eclipse PDT/Zend Studio

Tags: php, zend-studio, eclipse-pdt

When using Zend Studio to write views for a MVC framework, is there any way of having those variables autocomplete, perhaps using PHPdoc?

For example, I set a variable in a view called $cart which is an instance of my ShoppingCart class. When I type "$cart->", I'd like the IDE to pop up with all of the objects properties.

Answer (score 1):

in Netbeans it is possible to do the following:

```
/* @var $var Class */
```

not sure if it works in eclipse.